# How to modify updateSql script at liquibase?

Tags: sql-update, liquibase

I try  to modify updateSql script to enable us to change column data types .. but I did not find way .. so please How to modify this script ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be more precise with what you have tried and what you want to achieve. Also the error/issue you got during this.

Answer (score 1):

`updateSQL` is a helper command that allows you to inspect the SQL Liquibase will run while using the update command. This helps to correct any issues that may arise before running the command. Read more about it [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/updatesql.html)
If after running `updateSQL` you find the output incorrect, you can directly make changes/modify your original SQL script. (as this is the actual use of `updateSQL` script)

If you have already run `liquibase update` and now you want to modify column data type (of already created table) as you mentioned in your question, you may want to check out [modifyDataType](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/modify-data-type.html) support of liquibase.
Below is an example:

```
<changeSet  author="liquibase-docs"  id="modifyDataType-example">  
    <modifyDataType  catalogName="cat"  
            columnName="id"  
            newDataType="int"  
            schemaName="public"  
            tableName="person"/>  
</changeSet>
```

Or you can do it using `SQL tag`:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-sql" id="example-sql" context="migrate">
    <sql dbms="mysql">
      ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN password NVARCHAR(64)
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

I hope I got your question right as your question is unclear to me and this is all that I could summarize from what my understanding came out of your question.

Comment: "you can directly make changes/modify your original SQL script" , that is my question how to modify this script (I mean when I type updatesql it show the script ..  can I modify this script)??

Comment: Another feature that could help you is `modifySQL`. Please read about it [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/modify-sql.html), check out the example for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

you can not modify updateSQL script. The main case when using Liquibase is to prepare your changelogs that way, so the outputSql would be exactly what you need.